# dog does not implement pets (wrong type for speak method)

Tags: go

can't find the problem by my self ! thank you for your help, when i pass the empty struct to getPets() which is an interface receiver i was expecting an empty reference of the struct returns, but instead i got this error **dog does not implement pets (wrong type for speak method) ** that i can't  figure out it been 6 hours now that i am triyng

```
import "fmt"

type pets interface {
    speak(name []byte) dog
}

type dog struct {
    dogs []string
    name string
}

type cat struct {
    cats []string
    name string
}

func (d *dog) speak(name []byte) *dog {
    (*d).dogs = append(d.dogs, string(name))
    return d
}

// func (c *cat) speak(name []byte) *cat {
//  (*c).cats = append(c.cats, string(name))
//  return c
// }

func getPets(f pets) {
    fmt.Println(f.speak([]byte("hello")))
}

func main() {
    d := dog{}
    getPets(d)
```

Comment: The [compilation error](https://play.golang.org/p/WA0REPX9ljf) explains the problem  in detail.  The type dog has the method `speak([]byte) *dog`, but the interface wants `speak([]byte) dog`.  Note that `dog` and `*dog` are different types.

Comment: Stop trying to do inheritance based designs in Go now and forever: It does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pets interface wants a function `speak(name []byte) dog`, but the function you wrote for the dog type is `speak(name []byte) *dog`.

```
func (d *dog) speak(name []byte) dog {
    d.dogs = append(d.dogs, string(name))
    return *d
}
```

or

```
type pets interface {
    speak(name []byte) *dog
}

type dog struct {
    dogs []string
    name string
}

func (d *dog) speak(name []byte) *dog {
    d.dogs = append(d.dogs, string(name))
    return d
}
```

The problem is that `*dog` and `dog` are different types. `*dog` is a pointer to a `dog`.